# How to tell if heim joint is worn (tie rods)?

Tags: steering, xterra, tie-rod

So I have a Total Chaos aftermarket steering system on my Xterra. It's only seen 2 years of use - mostly as a daily driver with a fair bit of logging road washboard driving.

Having some knock in my steering, trying to figure out what's going on. I'm thinking my heim joint is worn, but I have no experience with these so don't know how much play is 'normal'.

Here is the video of the (potentially) worn heim: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4gocmqdfdv0e4l3/VID_20200118_125112.mp4?dl=0

You can see that the wheel has a fair bit of movement without any of the actual steering engaging - movement is just from the heim play. I'm assuming this is too much play and is worn out?

kinda crazy that it wore out in under 2 years with probably only 15,000km of driving, mostly pavement :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace that joint - if it is showing that much movement it needs replacing.

Comment: Posted this question on another 4x4 forum and unanimously folks agreed that the joint in my vid has so much movement it's completely worn out!